# The quotient stack by a smooth group action is algebraic

Tags: algebraic-geometry

Let $S$ be a scheme, $X$ be an $S$-algebraic space, $G$ a smooth group algebraic space over $S$.
Let $G$ act on $X$ by right.

Then we have the groupoid $s, t :X \times_S G \to X$, where $s(x, g) = xg, t(x, g) = x$.
Let $\mathscr{X}$ be the quotient stack of this groupoid.
Then is this stack algebraic?
i.e., are the morphisms $s, t$ smooth surjective?

The smoothness of $t$ is trivial.
What about $s$?
i.e., is the action morphism $X \times_S G \to X : (x, g) \mapsto xg$ smooth?

Comment: Don't know much about stacks, but I believe $s$ is the composition of the isomorphism $(x,g)\mapsto (xg,g)$ with $t$, so that might help

Comment: @Moisés Thank you very much!